# Equivalent of $btn-secondary-color on Bootstrap 4 Beta

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, twitter-bootstrap-4

I was using the variable `$btn-secondary-color` in the `_custom.scss` file, but this variable does not exist on Bootstrap 4 Beta. It seems that it has been replaced by this:

```
// _variables.scss

$theme-colors: (
  primary: $blue,
  secondary: $gray-600,
  success: $green,
  info: $cyan,
  warning: $yellow,
  danger: $red,
  light: $gray-100,
  dark: $gray-800
) !default;

// _buttons.scss
@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
  .btn-#{$color} {
    @include button-variant($value, $value);
  }
}
```

So how can I fix my code and reference the secondary color for buttons in the `_custom.scss`?

Comment: For future reference, this is the pull request in which the changes were made: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/22836

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's the best way, but I got the value I need by using:

```
color: map-get($theme-colors, secondary);
```

Comment: `theme-color("secondary")` is a maybe a little clearer in terms of readability, though ofc it does exactly what you did, a map-get on $theme-colors.